# What's the difference between namespacing a Ruby class and wrapping it in a module?

Tags: ruby, namespaces, constants

```rb
class Baz
end

module Foo
end

module Foo
  class Bar1 < Baz
    # ...
  end
end

class Foo::Bar2 < Baz
  # ...
end
```

I had thought that `Bar1` and `Bar2` should behave identically because I thought that wrapping the class declaration in `module Foo...end` and namespacing the class with `Foo::` were merely syntactic variants. However, I'm seeing these two differ in their behavior in a real application, so I must have been wrong!

**What exactly is the difference in behavior, if any, between `Bar1` and `Bar2`?**

Secondary question: Does the fact that they have an explicitly declared superclass (`Baz`) make a difference, or is that a red herring?

Comment: The difference is constant lookup [This Article](http://michaelprouty.com/blog/programming/2017/02/14/ruby-constant-lookup.html) seems to cover your exact scenario. [This One](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html) is an oldy but a goody and goes more in depth

Comment: @engineersmnky Yep, that looks like the ticket. You'd think I'd have been aware of this given the time I've put into investigating constant lookup (https://medium.com/@hoffm/a-puzzle-about-ruby-constants-e958d15dbada)!